# import an array in python

Tags: python, numpy

How can I import an array to python (numpy.arry) from a file and that way the file must be written if it doesn't already exist.

For example, save out a matrix to a file then load it back.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Checkout the entry on the [numpy example list](http://scipy.org/Numpy_Example_List#head-e20ed4935bc0f3edcb23420fe9d2617dbcd6b1ea). Here is the entry on .loadtxt()

```
>>> from numpy import *
>>>
>>> data = loadtxt("myfile.txt")                       # myfile.txt contains 4 columns of numbers
>>> t,z = data[:,0], data[:,3]                         # data is 2D numpy array
>>>
>>> t,x,y,z = loadtxt("myfile.txt", unpack=True)                  # to unpack all columns
>>> t,z = loadtxt("myfile.txt", usecols = (0,3), unpack=True)     # to select just a few columns
>>> data = loadtxt("myfile.txt", skiprows = 7)                    # to skip 7 rows from top of file
>>> data = loadtxt("myfile.txt", comments = '!')                  # use '!' as comment char instead of '#'
>>> data = loadtxt("myfile.txt", delimiter=';')                   # use ';' as column separator instead of whitespace
>>> data = loadtxt("myfile.txt", dtype = int)                     # file contains integers instead of floats
```

Comment: hello, thanks for answering, I can only doubt as he defines the path of where the file

Answer (score 10):

Another option is [`numpy.genfromtxt`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.genfromtxt.html), e.g:

```
import numpy as np
data = np.genfromtxt("myfile.dat",delimiter=",")
```

This will make `data` a numpy array with as many rows and columns as are in your file

Comment: Why is this answer less upvoted?  This solved my problem.  It seems more flexible, as well

Answer (score 1):

(I know the question is old, but I think this might be good as a reference for people with similar questions)

If you want to load data from an ASCII/text file (which has the benefit or being more or less human-readable and easy to parse in other software), numpy.loadtxt is probably what you want:

- http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.loadtxt.html

If you just want to quickly save and load numpy arrays/matrices to and from a file, take a look at numpy.save and numpy.load:

- http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.save.html
- http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.load.html

Answer (score 1):

In Python, Storing a bare python list as a numpy.array and then saving it out to file, then loading it back, and converting it back to a list takes some conversion tricks.  The confusion is because python lists are not at all the same thing as numpy.arrays:

```
import numpy as np
foods = ['grape', 'cherry', 'mango']
filename = "./outfile.dat.npy"
np.save(filename, np.array(foods))
z = np.load(filename).tolist()
print("z is: " + str(z))
```

This prints:

```
z is: ['grape', 'cherry', 'mango']
```

Which is stored on disk as the filename: `outfile.dat.npy`

The important methods here are the `tolist()` and `np.array(...)` conversion functions.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [SciPy cookbook](http://www.scipy.org/Cookbook/InputOutput). It should give you an idea of some basic methods to import /export data.

If you save/load the files from your own Python programs, you may also want to consider the [Pickle](http://docs.python.org/library/pickle.html) module, or cPickle.

Comment: Pickling is inappropriate for arrays - while you can do it, it will be slow as hell. Use np.save() to save in the .npy format or np.savez() to save a zipped archive of several arrays.